# Grub not recognizing windows on different ssd

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-10, menu

I have 2 ssds, one with windows 10, I decided to install ubuntu 20.04 on the other ssd. All worked fine but at first the grub menu didn't show and I booted to ubuntu automatically. Then I did some research and managed to make the grub menu pop up but it doesn't recognized windows 10. I tried update-grub but it doesn't work

Comment: You may have installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode and Windows was installed in UEFI mode. Please [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1271901/edit) and provide more information.

Comment: Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode

Comment: Check if Windows is using dynamic partitions.

Comment: And Windows fast startup which sets hibernation flag, is off. Windows turns that back on with updates and grub will not see nor boot Windows if hibernated. Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I found that if I press f12 while booting another menu pops up and I can boot windows from there

Comment: If both Ubuntu and Windows are in UEFI mode and they are in 2 different SSDs, is it possible that the two SSDs have their own ESP partitions? I am not sure if that is the case, if the Windows boot option would show up in the `grub`.